# error while using QT and OpenCV

Tags: qt, opencv, qt4

i am having the following error while trying to implement my first code with QT and OpenCV.

```
error C2039: 'videoCapture' : is not a member of 'cv'
```

In fact, i was testing the code of this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ONxIy8itRA).
I don't know why QT can not find the OpenCV libraries, well here is the OpenCV part in the project.pro :

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:\\opencv\\build\\include

LIBS += -LD:\\opencv\\bin\\Release\
    -lopencv_core245 \
    -lopencv_imgproc245 \
    -lopencv_highgui245 \
    -lopencv_ml245 \
    -lopencv_video245 \
    -lopencv_features2d245 \
    -lopencv_calib3d245 \
    -lopencv_objdetect245 \
    -lopencv_contrib245 \
    -lopencv_legacy245 \
    -lopencv_flann245
```

Comment: "error C2039: 'videoCapture' : is not a member of 'cv'" is not linkage error.

Comment: yes i solved it by changing it to "CvCapture* capWebcam;".
Thank you

Comment: FYI, you can answer and solve your own question so it shows as closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing it to "CvCapture* capWebcam".